# Data Structure and approach for @tagging like Facebook and Twitter?

Tags: database, facebook, database-design, twitter

I'm thinking about implementing a system similar Facebook/Twitter where, when a user types @ (or another special character), the user can select a username and "tag" them in a post. I know how to write the jQuery for this kind of behavior, but what does the actual data(base) structure look like for this kind of behavior?

I highly doubt the link is stored directly within the database. Since its possible to tag multiple things, what does this structure look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this is a problem of an actual design (the way I understood it).

With each user having a unique ID and a name, you query for the name and sent back the name from the database along with the ID. The link to the person is simply constructed from the ID since it always looks the same [...]?profile=12345678.

The connecions between members and "tagged things" would be simple join tables. I would create a single table for each taggable object (like "photo", "message",...) since it may increase performance but the rest sounds rather straight forward. Since each of this ressources has already a unique identifier (like ID or any other surrogate key) multiple tags are no problem within the join table (so user 123 can be in message 234 and 235 while user 456 can also be in message 235).

How to find WHERE the user is in the post: This is a server side issue IMO. When the message gets sent to the server, it needs to process it and turn a username into a link to the user. Since facebook doesn't allow editing of messages, you could simply replace the plain user name with a link to the user since editing is not a concern. Another possibility is to leave the "@" inside the message and try to parse it every time the post gets displayed. This is more complex and creates more overhead but you don't have HTML inside your database.

Comment: what about multiple tags in the same message. and how does it know WHERE the persons name in the post is?